# vb6 : mysql connection ok but database not shown

Tags: vb6, ado

Just want to show a list of `mysql` databases only. Is it possible or not ?

```
Public Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs1 As New ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim ConnString As String
    Dim db_name As String
    Dim db_server As String
    Dim db_port As String
    Dim db_user As String
    Dim db_pass As String

    ' fill the variable
    db_name = ""
    db_server = "localhost" '
    db_port = "3306"    'default port is 3306.
    db_user = "root"    'default user name or depend on your user name on mysql.
    db_pass = ""  'depend on your password on mysql.

    ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};SERVER=" & db_server & ";DATABASE=" & db_name & _
        ";UID=" & db_user & ";PWD=" & db_pass & ";PORT=" & db_port & ";OPTION=3"
    With Conn
        .ConnectionString = ConnString
        .Open
    End With

    Set rs1 = Conn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
    MsgBox rs1.Fields(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no reason to have a comment like "fill the variable"; this is obvious and just distracts the reader.

Comment: Try `Set rs1 = Conn.Execute("show databases")` or similar

Answer (score 0):

MS provides a special COM component for this purpose *(=work on a database's schema)*: ADOX (Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security). You need to add a project reference to it.

Assuming an active connection, here's how to list the tables:

```
Dim cat As ADOX.Catalog
Dim tbl As ADOX.Table

Set cat = New ADOX.Catalog
Set cat.ActiveConnection = cn ' Assumes cn is an active ADODB.Connection

For Each tbl In cat.Tables
    Debug.Print tbl.Name
Next tbl
```